# Execute a return with Watin without using System,Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}")

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, watin

I'm using WatiN to operate an automation script. It's a windows forms based solution and I'm using Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express to build my solution.

What's a way to use WatiN or some other native C# command to issue a return without having to have the screen focused on? (I'd like to be able to continue to work on other projects while the automated solution runs.

Thanks for any and all advice!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible to manipulate windows forms applications using WatiN in the first place.
You might want to consider White Framework for this.